# Unable to select an element for an Angular combox with auto search

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am having issue selecting clicking on an element and selecting an auto search from the corresponding result.

The element in question is an Angular JS combo box, which has an auto search functionality - something like the `Remote Data` combo box on this page - [link](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/?_ga=2.52023786.2139979356.1555306629-2001202407.1555306629#/material/combo-box/data-binding)

The corresponding HTML generated is

```
<div id="some_generic_id" style="margin-bottom: 16px">
  <div data-reactroot="" class="Select Select--multi is-searchable">
    <div class="Select-control">
      <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="some-generic-id-2">
        <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
          <input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns=""
            aria-haspopup="false" aria-activedescendant="some-generic-id-2" 
            value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px;">
          <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; 
                      height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px;
                      font-family: Arial; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; 
                      letter-spacing: normal;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </span>
      <span class="Select-arrow-zone">
        <span class="Select-arrow"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have used the following selectors as of now (apart from many others) -

Xpath -

```
//div[@id='some_generic_id']//div[@class='Select-control']
```

CSS Selectors -

```
#some_generic_id > div > div

#some_generic_id-2 > div > input
```

However, I'm always getting `element not interact-able` error everytime, which I'm failing to understand.

I've also used the `browser.actions().mouseMove()` methods along with the `executeScript()` method to click it using plain ol JS, but haven't had any success so far.

I see a `visibility :hidden` attribute in the `div` following the `input` tag - the `input` is actually want to click. Is this attribute messing up with how the `input` can be interacted? If this is the case, can someone explain why this is happening so?

Appreciate any pointers in solving the issue.

I am using `Protractor (version 5+)` with `Cucumber JS` and `async/await`

Edit : I've defined the locator in a separate file `locators.ts`.

```
import {browser, element,protractor,$,ElementFinder } from 'protractor';

export class Locators {
            public input_element : ElementFinder;

            constructor(){

            //these selectors I have tried
           this.input_element = element(by.xpath("//div[@id='some_generic_id']//div[@class='Select-control']"));

            //this.input_element = element(by.xpath("//span[@id='#some_generic_id-2']//input[@role='combobox']"));

        // this.input_element =$('#some_generic_id > div > div');
        // this.input_element = $('#some_generic_id-2 > div > input');
        // this.input_element = $('input[role=combobox]')
       }

        }
```

In the step definition file, I am using this selector as

```
When(/^I do some step $/,async()=>{
    await   (browser.actions().mouseMove(locators.input_element).click().perform());

   // await (browser.actions().mouseMove(locators.input_element).sendKeys('Aero').perform());
```

If I use any of the selectors mentioned above, I either get a `No element found using locator` or `Element No Interactable` error.

If I use a JS executor like this

```
   await (browser.executeScript("$('#some_generic_id-2 > div > input').click();"));
```

then the step is passed but there is no action performed on the element under question.

Comment: did you try using `input[role=combobox]` selector?

Comment: Show your code you tried so far.

Comment: Share your error and test file

Comment: Added the details of code and error. I cannot copy paste the exact error because of enterprise nature of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one

```
const inputBox = element(by.css('div.Select-input>input'));
await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', inputBox.getWebElement());
await inputBox.click();
await browser.actions().sendKeys('Aero').perform();
```